Asymptotically small submatrices of random matrices
Consider an ensemble of $N \times N$ random Hermitian matrices distributed according to some unitarily invariant measure
$$P(M) \mathrm{d}M = \frac{1}{Z_{N}} e^{-\mathrm{tr}[ Q(M)]}\mathrm{d}M,$$
for some choice of potential function $Q$, and where $Z_{N}$ is a normalization constant. The eigenvalue distribution of $M$ has a well-known characterization in terms of the orthogonal polynomials with respect to the weight function $w(x) = e^{-Q(x)}$.
Now consider the $n \times n$ submatrix $M_{n}$ consisting of the top left subblock of $M$. What can we say about the probability distribution of the eigenvalues of $M_{n}$ in the scaling limit $n, N \to \infty$ with $n/N \to 0$, i.e. where $M_{n}$ is large but asymptotically much smaller than $M$? If $M$ is drawn from the GUE then the answer is simple, but I would like to consider the generic case where there are correlations between matrix elements.
